# Could not SSH EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have an Amazon EC2 instance which is in running state (Green). It's security group has SSH inbound enabled.

Actually, I was able to login to this instance before couple of days. But it is not accessible via either SSH or port 80 (http).

Your help is appreciated in advance.

Thanks

Update:

**ssh -vvvv**

output:

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-52-53-163-182.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com [52.53.163.182] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 52.53.163.182 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host ec2-52-53-163-182.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection timed out
```

Comment: when you go to the aws console, click on your instance, and then at the bottom click on the "Monitoring" tab - is everything green?

Comment: @man0v Yes, everything looks good there. on Status Check tab "Instance reachability check passed" too.

Comment: if you use linux, can you ssh with `ssh -vvvv` and post the output?

Comment: @man0v Updated OP.

Comment: What security group do you use? Is it restricted to one IP only? Is it possible that your ip has changed?

Comment: @man0v It's allowed to all IPs.  SSH
 
TCP
 
22
 
0.0.0.0/0

Comment: It appears your machine has died... you have only reboot ahead of you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73704/discussion-between-prabhat-subedi-and-man0v).

Comment: Check if any service check failed in web AWS console. I experienced similar behavior with m5 generation instances which crashed without any reason and records in logs.

Comment: Can you ping the machine? Does it have an ellastic IP attached? If not, it could have changed during some restart.

Answer (score 0):

If you use m5 instance generation, check this AWS forum thread:
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=829554

There is some issue with m5 generation which results in stuck OS, as in your case. Only solution is stop/start instance from console.
As a workaround, I'd suggest switching to m4 until AWS team confirms that issue has been resolved.